# How to enlarge figures to take maximum available space?

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats, minipage, width

I am trying to put two figures side by side using minipage. But the figures are shrinking and not using the full page width. How to get figures that use the full page width?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{P1.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{P2.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using `\columnwidth` instead of the width of the minipages?

Comment: Full page width?  Do you man the width of the text area (\usepackage{showframe} or \usepackage[showframe]{geometry})?  BTW, you are adding a space between the two minipages, so they may not fit side by side.

Comment: @SHAONINANDI does the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{figure}[htp]

\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\caption{Two side by side figures filling the space, with some separation}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[1][4-5]
\begin{figure}[htp]

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\caption{Two side by side figures filling the space, with no separation}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[1][6-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using max textwidth with minor space between the figures

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-b}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

If no space required between the figures put a `%` after the first minipage

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-b}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

**edit --to prevent protruding image in to margin--with respect to suggestion by @mico**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.4975\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-b}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4975\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: In your first example, the second graph protrudes into the richt hand margin. Pls fix.

Comment: kindly guide how?

Comment: Change both instances of `{0.5\textwidth}` to, say, `{0.4975\textwidth}` and insert `\hfill` after the first instance of `\end{minipage}`. This leaves a gap of `\0.005\textwidth` between the images.

Comment: why does inserting `\quad` not give same result as `\hfill`

Comment: @jsbibra - \quad has a fixed width.  \hfill can be as small as 0pt and expands to fill the available space.